# SolrClient::query() Solr HTTP Error : 'Couldn't resolve host name'

Tags: solr, yii

`Solr` using with `Yii Framework` and getting this error:

`SolrClient::query() [<a href='solrclient.query'>solrclient.query</a>]: Solr HTTP Error: 
'Couldn't resolve host name'`

I have defined hostname: localhost:81 port: 8983

Tried many ways on using localhost but not getting right solution.

Comment: are you sure you're running Solr? On port 8983?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there's a separate 'port' field, don't put the port in the 'hostname' field.